# How to get all the text separately from the bracket using javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sentence stored in a variable.That sentence I need to extract into 4  parts depends on sentence which I have put into variables in my code,I can able to extract here and get into console but I am not getting the whole text of inside the bracket,only I am getting first words.Here is the code below.Can anyone please help me.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="messages">
```

### SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  regex = /.+\(|\d. \w+/g;
  maintext = "Welcome to project, are you a here(1. new user , 2. test user , 3. minor Accident or 4. Major Accident)";
  matches = maintext.match(regex);
  text_split0 = matches[0].slice(0, -1);
  text_split1 = matches[1];
  text_split2 = matches[2];
  text_split3 = matches[3];
  text_split4 = matches[4];
  console.log(text_split0);
  console.log(text_split1);
  console.log(text_split2);
  console.log(text_split3);
  console.log(text_split4);
  $(".messages").append('<li>'+text_split0+'</li><li>'+text_split1+'</li><li>'+text_split2+'</li><li>'+text_split3+'</li><li>'+text_split4+'</li>');
 // $("li:contains('undefined')").remove()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildMessages(text) {
    let messages = text.split(/\d\.\s/);
    messages.shift();
    messages.forEach((v)=>{
        let msg = v.replace(/\,/,'').replace(/\sor\s/,'').trim();
        $('.messages').append(`<li>${msg}</li>`);
        // console.log(`<li>${msg}</li>`);
    });
}

let sentenceToParse = "Welcome to project, are you a here(1. new user , 2. test user , 3. minor Accident or 4. Major Accident)";

buildMessages(sentenceToParse);
```

- Use the `split` function on the String, keying on the digits (e.g. `1.`), you will get the preface and each of the steps into an array.
- Use the `shift` function on the Array removes the unneeded preface.
- Use `forEach` to iterate over the values in the array, clean up the text.
- Using `replace` to first remove commas, then remove `or` with spaces on either side.
- Use `trim` to remove leading and training whitespace.

At this point, your array will have sanitized copy for use in your `<li>` elements.

If you're only concerned with working through a regex and not re-factoring, the easiest way may be to use an online regex tool where you provide a few different string samples. Look at https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: If you explain what you changed and why yours works this could be a good answer. As it is, a code-dump with no explanation is not particularly useful to future readers.

Comment: can you please use simple way,I think we need to fix only regular expression here regex = /.+(|\d. \w+/g; to resolve this issue

Comment: We need to fix only regular expression  here regex = /.+\(|\d. \w+/g;No need to use loop here that will create problem in my application.just I need to get whole value like - Welcome to project, are you a here
1. new user
2. test user
3. minor Accident 
4. Major Accident

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Try another approach, cause regex for this isn't the best way. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // First part of sentence.
  var mainText = "Welcome to project, are you a here(";
  // Users array.
  var USERS = ['new user', 'test user', 'minor Accident', 'Major Accident'];
  var uSize = USERS.length;

  // Construct string & user list dynamically.
  for(var i = 0; i < uSize; i++) {
    var li = $('<li/>').text(USERS[i]);

    if(i === uSize - 1)
      mainText += (i+1) + ". " + USERS[i] + ")";
    else if(i === uSize - 2)
      mainText += (i+1) + ". " + USERS[i] + " or ";
    else
      mainText += (i+1) + ". " + USERS[i] + " , ";

    $(".messages").append(li);
  }
  console.log(mainText); // You will have you complete sentence.
}
```

Why that way is better? Simple, you can add or remove users inside the user array. String together with your user list will be updated automatically. I hope that help you.

Comment: I replaced my script with your code $(document).ready(function() {
   regex = /.+\(|\d. \w+/g;
  maintext = "Welcome to project, are you a here(1. new user , 2. test user , 3. minor Accident or 4. Major Accident)";
  matches = maintext.match(regex);
  matches[0] = matches[0].slice(0, -1);    
$.each(matches, function(idx, match) {
  var li = $('<li/>').text(match);
  $('.messages').append(li);
});
}); still I am getting same output,I am getting only first word of text inside brackets  Welcome to project, are you a here
1. new
2. test
3. minor
4. Major

Comment: We need to fix only regular expression  here regex = /.+\(|\d. \w+/g;

Comment: We need to fix only regular expression  here regex = /.+\(|\d. \w+/g;No need to use loop here that will create problem in my application.just I need to get whole value like - Welcome to project, are you a here
1. new user
2. test user
3. minor Accident 
4. Major Accident